# Xamarin studio UIImageView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

I can load a picture to a UImageView with I click a button, but not from a timer. why is that ? and how can I fix it ?

here is my code :

```
void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Patter_Function();
    switch_Function();
}



void switch_Function()
{

    image1 = new UIImage();
    image1 = UIImage.FromBundle("heart");

    image2 = new UIImage();
    image2 = UIImage.FromFile( @"White_Sharingan.png");

    image3 = new UIImage();
    image3 = UIImage.FromFile("snow.png");

    image4 = new UIImage();
    //image4.//FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");



        switch (Patter_1[switch_Counter].Move0) { 
        case 0 :
            Box_1.Image =  image1;
            break;
                case 1 :
                Box_1.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 2 :
                Box_2.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 3:
                Box_3.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 4:
                Box_4.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 5:
                Box_5.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 6:
                Box_6.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 7:
                Box_7.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 8:
                Box12.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 9:
                Box_9.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 10:
                Box_10.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 11:
                Box_11.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 12:
                Box8.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 13:
                Box_13.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 14:
                Box_14.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 15:
                Box_15.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 16:
                Box_16.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 17:
                Box_17.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 18:
                Box_18.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 19:
                Box_19.Image = image1;
                break;
                case 20:
                Box_20.Image = image1;
                break;}


        switch (Patter_1[switch_Counter].Move1)
        {
            case 0:
                Box_1.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 1:
                Box_2.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 2:
                Box_2.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 3:
                Box_3.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 4:
                Box_4.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 5:
                Box_5.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 6:
                Box_6.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 7:
                Box_7.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 8:
                Box12.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 9:
                Box_9.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 10:
                Box_10.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 11:
                Box_11.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 12:
                Box8.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 13:
                Box_13.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 14:
                Box_14.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 15:
                Box_15.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 16:
                Box_16.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 17:
                Box_17.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 18:
                Box_18.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 19:
                Box_19.Image = image2;
                break;
            case 20:
                Box_20.Image = image2;
                break;
        }

    switch (Patter_1[switch_Counter].Move2)
    {
        case 0:
            Box_1.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 1:
            Box_2.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 2:
            Box_2.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 3:
            Box_3.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 4:
            Box_4.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 5:
            Box_5.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 6:
            Box_6.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 7:
            Box_7.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 8:
            Box12.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 9:
            Box_9.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 10:
            Box_10.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 11:
            Box_11.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 12:
            Box8.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 13:
            Box_13.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 14:
            Box_14.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 15:
            Box_15.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 16:
            Box_16.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 17:
            Box_17.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 18:
            Box_18.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 19:
            Box_19.Image = image3;
            break;
        case 20:
            Box_20.Image = image3;
            break;
    }

    switch (Patter_1[switch_Counter].Move3)
    {
        case 0:
            Box_1.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 1:
            Box_2.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 2:
            Box_2.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 3:
            Box_3.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 4:
            Box_4.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 5:
            Box_5.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 6:
            Box_6.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 7:
            Box_7.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 8:
            Box12.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 9:
            Box_9.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 10:
            Box_10.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 11:
            Box_11.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 12:
            Box8.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 13:
            Box_13.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 14:
            Box_14.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 15:
            Box_15.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 16:
            Box_16.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 17:
            Box_17.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 18:
            Box_18.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 19:
            Box_19.Image = image4;
            break;
        case 20:
            Box_20.Image = image4;
            break;
    }

    switch_Counter++;
    if (switch_Counter >4  )
    {
        switch_Counter = 0;
    }
}
```

I used the debugger, so I know the code is getting to the line
but it is not doing anything when it get there 
the bebugger says:
UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoke from the UI Thread.

Is there a why around that ?

Answer (score 0):

Any operation you involve in modifying UI view, you will need to do it under UI/Main thread. So put the code inside the lambda of:

```
InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
    // manipulate UI controls
});
```